# Print all possibilities by rotating a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

How to rotate a string in javascript and print the rotated versions of string **without using any javascript functions**, only `for` loops.

Given a string:

```
"hell"
```

Output:

```
"lhel", "llhe", "ellh", "hell"
```

I have tried but not succeded

```js
    var str1 = "hell";

    
    let i = 0;
    let len = str1.length - 1;
    let temp;
    
    for (let j = 0; j < len+1; j++) {
        temp = str1[len]
        while (i < len) {
            console.log(str1[i]);
            temp += str1[i];
            i++;
        }
        console.log(temp);
        //console.log(typeof temp, typeof str1)
        str1 = temp;
    }
```

Comment: sounds like a homework assignment

Comment: @GottZ There is nothing wrong asking for help about a homework assignment, OP showed attempts to solve it

Comment: You're off to a good start. You clearly know that you can get a character from a string via `str[n]` where `str` is the string and `n` is an index in it, and that `+` can combine characters into longer strings. So your task is to work out how you would combine those two operations to perform this task. When you run into trouble, step through your code with the debugger built into your IDE and/or browser to see exactly what's going on. You might even try it in the real world with coins for characters, figuring out the logic it takes to rearrange them the way you want. Happy coding!

Comment: @GottZ Yes, its an interview question, I am unable to solve it. Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there ! There is one thing missing, `i` should be reset at each iteration of the `for` loop, otherwise, the `while (i < len)` will be "played" only once :

```js
var str1 = "hell";

let len = str1.length - 1;
let temp;
    
for (let j = 0; j < len+1; j++) {
    let i = 0;  // <-------------------- notice this
    temp = str1[len]
    while (i < len) {
        //console.log(str1[i]);
        temp += str1[i];
        i++;
    }
    console.log(temp);
    //console.log(typeof temp, typeof str1)
    str1 = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take a nested loop and get the characters at the position of `i` and `j` and take the [reminder operator `%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) for preventing characters outside of the string.

```js
var string = "hell",
    i, j,
    temp;

for (i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    temp = '';
    for (j = 1; j <= string.length; j++) temp += string[(i + j) % string.length];
    console.log(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this method. Basically you have two loops the first loop with (i) is for the possibilities the second one is for the shifting

```js
var strValue = "hell";
var temp;
for(var i = 0; i < strValue.length; i++){
  temp = "";
  for(var j = 1; j < strValue.length; j++){
    temp += strValue[j];
  }
  temp += strValue[0]
  strValue = temp;
  console.log(strValue)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In first loop add all symbols which indexes are greater then amount of shift steps (i in this case).

And add rest symbols after it the second loop.

```js
const str = 'hello';

for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  let shifted = '';

  for (let j = i; j < str.length; j++) {
    shifted += str[j];
  }
  
  for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    shifted += str[j];
  }
  
  console.log(shifted);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i know this has already been answered so.. this is how i'd do it.
maybe you can learn from it.

```js
const str = "hell";

// this loop will set the offset. so if it's 1, "hell" will become "ellh"
for (let offset = 0; offset < str.length; offset++) {
  // this will contain the final string
  let output = "";

  // here we iterate through all the characters
  for (let index = 0; index < str.length; index++) {
    // and use modulo to switch 5 to 1 (in case length is 4)
    output += str[(index + offset) % str.length];
  }

  // there we go
  console.log(output);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
let str = 'hell';



for(let i=0;i<str.length;i++){
 str = str.substring(1,str.length) + str[0];
 console.log(str);
}
```